# VS2012 Page Inspector ignoring text-shadow style

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, page-inspector

I'm having in issue in VS2012 where page inspector appears to be ignoring the css directive:

> text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #aaaaaa;

This is part of a style as follows:

> h1 {
>     font-size: 56px; 
>     text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #aaaaaa; 
>     text-indent: -61px;
>     float: left;
>          margin-bottom: 5px;
>   }

When 'Viewed in Page Inspector' and the header is 'inspected' it shows the other four styles but there is no reference to 'text-shadow'.

If I view the page in IE10 or Chrome the shadow works perfectly.  It's almost as if Page Inspector is hosting an earlier IE than IE10 - but I'm not sure how that's possible.

Much befuddlement here!  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page inspector might be slightly different from pure IE 10 on your computer.
They have different user agents at least:

Page inspector:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; Eureka/1.0)
```

IE10:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
```

Is there any problem with it? There is probably nothing you can do about it.

**EDIT:**
Add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

to your markup.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure what Eureka is, but Trident is the main engine isn't it and this is the same.  I guess if I can avoid having to open up a browser window each time I want to see a format change then that would genuinely save me a chunk of time over the course of a project.  Also I've googled quite extensively and not seen this mentioned before - and it does seem to be contra to the Page Inspector design aims.  Will keep on searching, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I'd consider to submit a bug through http://connect.microsoft.com/. Maybe they'll fix it in the next update.

Comment: Thanks - yes have done.  Can't help feeling maybe it's a config issue somewhere (maybe the hosted IE10 in Page Inspector is locked into IE7 compatibility mode or somesuch)

Comment: Try to force IE10 using <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

Comment: Rocky!  That does it! Thank you! - do you want to leave your response as an answer and I can then 'tick it' I think?